# How to rewrite page name (url) reported by amp-analytics in Google AMP?

Tags: google-analytics, amp-html, amp-analytics

I'm trying to send a custom page name (page url) to Google Analytics from an AMP page. Normally I would send the custom page name like this:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {'page': 'myPageName'});
```

But amp-analytics can only customized from this JSON code:

```
    <amp-analytics type="googleanalytics" id="analytics1">
      <script type="application/json">
      {
        "vars": {
          "account": "UA-664228-1"
        },

        "triggers": {

          "trackPageview": {
            "on": "visible",
            "request": "pageview",
            "vars": {
              "title": "<?php the_title() ?>",
              "ampdocUrl": "${canonicalUrl}"
            }
          }
        }
      </script>
    </amp-analytics>
```

How do I modify the page name (page url) that's reported back to Google Analytics?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I figured it out. You add a documentLocation variable. Here's how:

```
 <amp-analytics type="googleanalytics" id="analytics1">
  <script type="application/json">
  {
    "vars": {
      "account": "UA-664228-1"
    },

    "triggers": {

      "trackPageview": {
        "on": "visible",
        "request": "pageview",
        "vars": {
          "title": "<?php the_title() ?>",
          "ampdocUrl": "${canonicalUrl}",
          "documentLocation": "myCustomPage"
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</amp-analytics>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [variable substiution](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-var-substitutions.md).